# How to create a service on Ubuntu Upstart

Tags: java, upstart, services, jar

I have a Java executable program that I can run by typing `java -jar abc.jar` in terminal.
How can I run it as a service? I want to run it as a service like by typing `service abc start`.

Comment: A more complete answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/create-services-in-linux-start-up-in-linux?newreg=4c8689303cb94ff58057fc88769c0880 Basically, in Ubuntu you can create a script for /etc/init.d which can start/stop/restart your service.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Make sure you're on 14.04. Ubuntu 16.04 (and above) uses systemd, not Upstart.**

A Upstart script is a script file placed at `/etc/init/` and ending in `.conf`.

It requires 2 sections: one to indicate when to start, and another with the command to execute.

The easiest script to start with your sample is:

```
# myprogram.conf
start on filesystem
exec /usr/bin/java -jar /path_to/program
```

Created as root under `/etc/init/myprogram.conf`.

If your script requires more than one command line, use the `script` section instead of the `exec` line:

```
# myprogram.conf
start on filesystem
script
    /usr/bin/java -jar /path_to/program
    echo "Another command"
end script
```

To enable bash completion for your service, add a symlink into `/etc/init.d` folder:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init/myprogram.conf /etc/init.d/myprogram
```

Then try start and stop it:

```
sudo service myprogram start
```

According the [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start), you can create `pre-start`/`post-start` and `pre-stop`/`post-stop` commands to be executed.

Additionally, I read you want to check if a process is running. Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) and maybe use the `pre-start` section.

Comment: Maybe you need make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/myprogram`. CAUTION: your answered method not works in Ubuntu 16.04!

Comment: @juliocesar 16.04 uses systemd, not Upstart.

Comment: `start on` is not a necessary stanza. As you can read [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-with-no-stop-on-or-start-on): _Such a job can only be controlled by an Administrator_.

Comment: @SuB yeap, but then the job will not start automatically, and it was clear that the question author want something acting like a service, i.e., starting automatically.

Comment: Yea. I know. just added a comment to complete your answer.

Comment: On Ubuntu16.04, I try to add kafka service, but said: Failed to start kafka.service: Unit kafka.service not found.

Comment: @linrongbin 16.04 uses systemd, not Upstart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an upstart.  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Upstart is (IMHO) a disaster compared to good ol' SysV init scripts. Upstart is FAR more effort with little upside to the added work.  With that said, I suspect there will be a few upstart defenders out there that will take me to task for me stating the obvious ;-)

Comment: It's just a file in /etc/init/yourservice.conf with a line indicating when to start, and another to the exec command. Fedora uses upstart too. Additionally, even Debian is changing its starting schema to SystemD, which will be Ubuntu schema in the future.