# How to convert a command to start a server to a service?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

Hi I have a command like below that I use to start a server on a port and I stop it by doing Ctrl+C usign ssh

```
./dapperdox -spec-dir=examples/specifications/tc -bind-addr 129.19.20.55:4096
```

Problem is it stops after sometime. Can I convert this command to a service like

```
service dapperdox start/stop/restart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a systemd service file e.g.

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/dapperdox.service
[Unit]
Description=This is dapperdox
Wants=network-online.target
After=

[Service]
Type=forking
User=dapperdox
ExecStart=/sbin/startproc /full/path/to/dapperdox -spec-dir=examples/specifications/tc -bind-addr 129.19.20.55:4096
ExecStop=/sbin/killproc -TERM /full/path/to/dapperdox

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF
```

Now try if you can start it.

```
sudo systemctl start dapperdox.service
```

Adjust the different things as you need them.

Afterwards you want to enable it so it starts during boot.

```
sudo systemctl enable dapperdox.service
```

Comment: hi can you show me the same thing using Upstart. My Digital Ocean Ubuntu does support systemctl

Comment: What ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS,
Release:        14.04

Comment: Try that one https://askubuntu.com/questions/351879/how-to-create-a-service-on-ubuntu-upstart