# How to check the process is already running or not

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

I want to check the particular process in already running or not.

I refereed [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c).

But I didn't get any specific solution. Following is the example that I tried:
I have created `abc.sh` file and run this script on background, like `sh abc.sh &`.

Now this file is running on background and I fire the `ps aux | grep "abc"` command.

Following is the output of this command:

```
prakash     3594  0.0  0.0   4388   820 pts/0    S+   16:44   0:00 grep --color=auto abc
```

After that I stop the `abc.sh` running script and fire the same command `ps aux | grep "abc"` command.

But I am getting same output like:

```
prakash     3594  0.0  0.0   4388   820 pts/0    S+   16:44   0:00 grep --color=auto abc
```

Is there any other way to find the process is running or not?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Every process will be listed in the output of `ps aux`; whether running, sleeping, zombie or stopped.

However, in your case, since you ran the process using `sh abc.sh`, `sh` is the application(shell) that is running and not `abc.sh`. Hence, `ps aux` will not contain the process `abc.sh` because of which `grep` could not yield any result.

So, the correct way you should have used it is as:

```
ps aux | grep sh
```

This may also return you other process that are running having the string `sh` anywhere in their output of `ps aux`.

You should note that the process will be "running" when the output of `ps aux` has its `STAT` as `R`. If it is something other than that, it is not running at the instance you fired the command to check the running processes. The different process states can be found in the man page for ps:

```
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    running or runnable (on run queue)
S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

You could as well run the `top` command to check if the process is running or sleeping and the amount of CPU, RAM it is consuming. (This will again list your process as `sh`).

However, if you do want your process to be listed as `abc.sh`, then you should have the first line of the script you are running as:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

so that the shell will know what application to use to run the script(sh in this case, change it to `#!/bin/bash` for bash) and then provide executable permissions to the process using:

```
chmod +x /path/to/abc.sh
```

replacing `/path/to/` with the location of the `abc.sh` file and then run `abc.sh` using

```
/path/to/abc.sh
```

again replacing `/path/to/` with the location of the `abc.sh` file.

Comment: One quick question. what is stat `S+` means

Comment: But you can find the difference between running processes and not running processes through the output of `ps aux | grep filename` command.

Comment: @TechGuru: It means that the process is sleeping in the foreground, refer to the manual page of ps for more.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: I get an error: **Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc**

Comment: @PrakashVHolkar regarding the `ps` manual, it means it's "in the foreground process group". A foreground process is basically a process which is tied to a terminal one way or an other.

Answer (score 7):

My problem with `grep` is that it's a whole-line parser. In your example, you're searching for "abc" but it's pulling back the instance of `grep` (that's looking for "abc"). A bit circular. You can filter that out but I find all that a little perverse.

I would turn to `awk` for a little panache.

```
ps aux | awk '$12=="abc.sh"'
```

`awk` splits the lines into fields based on whitespace (by default). Fields $11+ are the command column(s) so if the command is "sh abc.sh ...", `$11` will be `sh` and `$12` will be `abc.sh`.

If you want to control the output or chain on with Bash's `&&` and `||` operators, you can but you'll need to be a little more clever. `grep` will exit with status code 1 (technical fail, triggers `||`) if nothing is found but `awk` will always exit code 0. We can change this by telling it to exit if it finds something and throw a 1 if it doesn't:

```
ps aux | awk '$12=="abc.sh" {exit 0} END{exit 1}' && echo running || echo not running
```

Of course if you just care about writing output to the screen, you could do that all in `awk`:

```
ps aux | awk '$12=="abc.sh" {print "running"; exit} END{print "not running"}'
```

Comment: It does not detect `emacs --daemon` on my end as a process

Answer (score 5):

The right way to check in the current bash session if a process started in background, like `sh abc.sh &`, is already running or not is to use `jobs` builtin command.

Example:

```
$ sh abc.sh &
[1] 6917
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sh abc.sh &
```

That's mean that the `sh abc.sh` process started in background is running. If the process has finished you will see something like:

```
[1]+  Done                    sh abc.sh
```

If you have more processes running in background, you can restrict the output only to the 
`sh abc.sh` process using:

```
jobs sh
```

See `help jobs` for more info.

The above method will work only in the current session of bash. But if you are in another bash session (e.g. in another terminal window or tab, or in a script), aside from:

```
ps aux | grep "[s]h bin/test.sh"
```

you can use also:

```
pgrep -a sh
```

which seems more simple to me. If you will see your typed command in the output (`sh abc.sh` in this case), that's means that the process is still running. If not, the process has finished.

Answer (score 3):

If your script is currently running, it must be shown by `ps aux` command. If it not shown by `ps`, then there may be your script execution is currently terminated.

Output of `ps` like this means your script is currently not running,

```
$ ps aux | grep hm.sh
avinash   6386  0.0  0.0  15940   932 pts/16   S+   17:34   0:00 grep --color=auto hm.sh
```

If it shows like this, which means your script is currently running.

```
$ ps aux | grep hm.sh
avinash   6454  0.0  0.0  16616  1384 pts/16   S+   17:35   0:00 /bin/bash ./hm.sh
avinash   6535  0.0  0.0  15940   932 pts/27   R+   17:35   0:00 grep --color=auto hm.sh
```

It's all based on the contents of the script.

For example, if you create a script like this. It displays the message HI on execution. It takes a few seconds to display the output and got terminated after it produces the final result.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HI"
```

But if your script like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
```

It takes some minutes to get the process terminated. On the meantime if you run `ps aux | grep filename` command, it will be shown on the output. Because the script is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use [pgrep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) to check if the process in running

```
pgrep -c "process name"
```

what this command does is count how many process were found with the name "process name" and returns thier number [0 is the process was not found]

Answer (score -2):

- if you want to check all processes then use 'top'
- if you want to know processes run by java then use `ps -ef | grep java`
- if other process then just use `ps -ef | grep xyz` or simply `/etc/init.d xyz status`
- if through any code like `.sh` then `./xyz.sh status`

Comment: -1 While these commands are useful under some circumstances they will still be useless to someone who doesn't know these circumstances. In each case you either don't explain them enough or your explanation is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

if you simply want to check whether there is any under process then go to that directory and type `ll -tr` if you see `.csv` or `.work` etc at the end of the file then it means under process else not.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Listing the contents of a directory will not tell you if a process is running. The file extension `.csv` is for comma delimited files which is not related to a running process.