# Open file if not already open with .sh script

Tags: bash, scripts

I got this script that opens an `.html` file, but I want to change it to only opening it if it isn't open yet.
Does anyone know some lines that have to be added in order to achieve this?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
fileFragment=$"*project/html/index.html"
fullPath=$(find ../ -path $fileFragment)
xdg-open $fullPath &
```

> EDIT
>   I would like a generic solution which is why I kept the question so simple, it's not about browsers, it's about any file I opened using `xdg-open`, I already specified it by providing this example, I don't want to specify it anymore to specific browsers.
>   But if there is no easy generic solution then I'd rather have an answer for my specific case than none: So in my case I'm using firefox.

Answer (score 1):

> The following solution only works for commands that *keep running* until you close the program/tab. Unfortunately that’s not the case for most GUI programs and `xdg-open`. In the case of Firefox one could [get a list of URLs currently opened](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Get_the_current_or_all_Firefox_tab_urls_in_Bash.html) and `grep` it, but that’s a neither generic nor ideal solution. As for testing whether a program is running, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/157779/507051).

---

You can use `lockfile` from the [`procmail` package [image: Install procmail]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/procmail). As [its `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/lockfile.1.html) holds an example exactly matching your use case, I’ll just quote it:

> Suppose you want to make sure that access to the file "important" is
>   serialised, i.e., no more than one program or  shell  script  should 
>   be allowed to access it.  For simplicity's sake, let's suppose that it is a shell script.  In this case you could solve it like this:
>
> ```bsh
> ...
> lockfile important.lock
> ...             
> access_"important"_to_your_hearts_content
> ...
> rm -f important.lock
> ...
> ```
>
> Now  if  all the scripts that access "important" follow this guideline, you will be assured that at most one script will be executing between the `lockfile` and the `rm` commands.

By default, every other script will wait for the file to be unlocked again, testing every eight seconds by default (change with e.g. `lockfile -5 important.lock` for five seconds). If you just want to check whether it’s locked, you can use the classic `test` command:

```bsh
if [ -e important.lock ]; then
  # stuff to do if locked
else
  # stuff to do if not locked
fi
```

Comment: Could you complete your example by adding my existing script? I'm an absolute beginner on Ubuntu scripts. I do not know what to put in place of the 4 `...` parts - and how do I 'use' lockfile from procmail? Do you mean I need to `sudo apt-get install procmail` before being able to use that script?

Comment: I think my question is very easy to understand but I added some more info for ya, I want NOTHING to happen when I execute this script and there is ANY browser window/tab/whatever open with that file. If it's too complex I'm happy with any easy solutions that still make it work like checking if a browser is running at all

Comment: Thank you, for now I am using the solution from an answer to the question you linked! I don't know how to use URL-Lists script in my example.