# How to determine whether a process is running or not in the current workspace to make a conditional shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, workspaces, window-manager

This is more like a follow up of this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c).

I'm using i3-tiling window manager and I'm trying to figure out if a Firefox instance is running IN A SPECIFIC WORKSPACE or not.

Now,

`pgrep -x firefox` works flawlessly it really only tells you that if a program is running and not much about where it is running, or in which workspace is it running?

Is there any way for me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The second column of the command `wmctrl -lx` indicates the workspace the window is currently on. The `-x` switch also shows the window class. This provides you all information needed to determine whether one or more windows of a certain application are open in a specific workspace. Note that `wmctrl` starts counting from 0 to denote the first workspace.