# Check the closure of an application in the shell script

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I am using version 20.04 of Kubuntu. How can I check the closure of an application using shell script?

For example, when I leave Code Visual Studio, print out the message `You are logged out.` in the terminal.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) may help you.

Comment: Logged out and closed are not the same. It is unclear what you want to check.

Comment: I mean exit the program :)   Your link was very helpful